# Display wordpress posts in ascending order

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I am trying to display wordpress posts in ascending instead of descending order.

The code I am using in my template is below

```
<?php 

                    $temp = $wp_query;
                    $wp_query = null;
                    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
                    $wp_query->query('showposts=24&post_type=movie&orderby=ASC' . '&paged=' . $paged);

                    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

                 ?>
```

however this is not working.

Does anyone know why?

Any help would be great
D

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-posts-in-ascending-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok but,

```
$wp_query->query('showposts=24&post_type=movie&order=ASC' . '&paged=' . $paged);
```

The difference is: "order", not "orderby".

Comment: Good answer, and orderby is used to tell WP what is your order-key... example : orderby='date', or orderby='title', orderby='author' etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, was losing my mind over something small. Also thank you for the feedback :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 

                $temp = $wp_query;
                $wp_query = null;
                $wp_query = new WP_Query();
                $wp_query->query('showposts=24&post_type=movie&order=ASC' . '&paged=' . $paged);

                while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
```

Try this. There was just a small mistake that you were trying to order by which is not used with wp_query.